# Prove that if $ h \circ f = g $ then $ h $ is an $A$-algebra homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B,\ g:A\rightarrow C$ be ring homomorphisms. An $A$-algebra homomorphism $h:B\rightarrow C$ is a ring homomorphism which is also an $A$-module homomorphism. 
Please prove that if $h \circ f = g$ then $h$ is an $A$-algebra homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $h(ax)=h(f(a)x)=h(f(a))h(x)=g(a)h(x)=ah(x)$ for all $a\in A$ and $x\in B$. (Note that $B$ is an $A$-module via $f$, that is, $ax:=f(a)x$ for all $a\in A$ and $x\in B$, while $C$ is an $A$-module via $g$.)

**Edit.** The question was unclear and I assumed the $h$ is a ring homomorphism, otherwise the claim being (almost) obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But why are the following right: $h\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)=h\left(b_{1}\right)+h\left(b_{2}\right)$ , $ h\left(b_{1}\cdot b_{2}\right)=h\left(b_{1}\right)\cdot h\left(b_{2}\right) $ ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Let $A = k[x]$, $B = k[x,y]$, and $C = k[x]$. Define $f$ and $g$ by $x \rightarrow x$. Now I take $h$ to be the identity on the subring $k[x] \subset k[x,y]$ where the inclusion is the canonical one. I can freely define $h$ outside of this subring to be anything I want, and it will satisfy all the hypotheses. In particular, sending $y \rightarrow x$ and $y^2 \rightarrow x$ will mean $h$ is not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: I completely agree. Don't we need $f$ to be surjective for the above to hold.

Comment: Certainly that would be sufficient, as would YACP's take on the question.